# Embedding dataframe plot on figure canvas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

Despite the ample matplotlib documentation at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html
I'm struggling with the simple task of embedding a dataframe plot on a figure canvas in a tkinter GUI.

I've loaded all the relevant packages and created my dataframe, named "df", inside a tkinter master window named "root".

The problem, which likely stems from an inadequate understanding of how figures work, comes down to the following lines of code

```
fig=df.plot()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP)
```

The error message I receive states, "AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'"

Comment: Does `df.plot()` return a `matplotlib.figure.Figure`? It looks like it returns a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` object instead. I think that `FigureCanvasTkAgg`'s first argument should a figure

Comment: Yes, df.plot() works. However, the command print(type(df.plot())) indicates <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>

Comment: I don't know much about `matplotlib` but it seems that `df.plot()` returns a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object but `FigureCanvasTkAgg` takes only a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object. So you need to find a way to get the `Figure` object from the `AxesSubplot`.

Comment: I see. That's the gap in my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TheLizzard's comment is correct, `df.plot()` does not returns a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` but a  `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` and `fig` should be a `Figure`.

However, `df.plot()` can take the matplotlib `AxesSubplot` in argument (the `ax` option). So you can create the subplot in the figure, then plot your `DataFrame` in the subplot:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100) # create the figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   # create the subplot
df.plot(ax=ax)  # plot df in ax

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: I was just guessing from the documentation :D. Nice answer btw